# using plot3D to color rows in specific color

Tags: r, rgl

I have a table `A` with 4000 rows and 3 columns, where x y z look like

```
x  y  z
1  3  6
2  4  6
3  5  6
5  2  5
```

I want to draw it with plot3D

```
library(plot3D)
library(rgl)
plot3d(A)
```

However, I want to make row 1-1000 color in red, 2000-3000 color in black,etc. How to get it please?

Update: thanks for nongkrong's answer. I have the following code works:

```
plot3d(A,col=rep(1:4,each=1000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something along the lines of

```
with(yourData, scatter3D(x, y, z, col=rep(1:4, each=1000)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it working for plot3D or scatterplot3D please?